# checkbox in docusign Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I added checkboxTab in envelopedefinition. 
but still did not see check box in document. what am I doing wrong? I want to add signHere, Initial and checkbox in PDF file.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <emailSubject>cvCurrentPORSignatureRequest.EmailSubjectOut</emailSubject>
   <emailBlurb>cvCurrentPORSignatureRequest.EmailBodyOut</emailBlurb>
   <status>sent</status>
   <documents>lvMultiDocumentNamesXMLText</documents>
   <recipients>
       <signers>
           <signer>
               <recipientId>1</recipientId>
               <email>cvCurrentPORSignatureRequest.RecipientEmailAddress</email>
               <name>cvCurrentPORSignatureRequest.RecipientNameOut</name>
               <tabs>
                   <signHereTabs>...</signHereTabs>
                   <initialHereTabs>...</initialHereTabs>
                   <CheckBoxTabs>
                       <documentId>1</documentId>
                       <CheckBox>
                           <anchorString>ShipTo:</anchorString>
                           <anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>
                           <anchorYOffset>2</anchorYOffset>
                           <anchorUnits>Inches</anchorUnits>
                           <xPosition>2</xPosition>
                           <yPosition>2</yPosition>
                           <name>CheckBox</name>
                           <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                           <Selected>true</Selected>
                           <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
                           <Shared>false</Shared>
                           <tabLabel>CheckBoxLabel1</tabLabel>
                           <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                           <templateLocked>False</templateLocked>
                       </CheckBox>
                   </CheckBoxTabs>
               </tabs>
           </signer>
       </signers>
   </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: Couple of items to help troubleshoot off the bat: 1) confirm that the actual text is present on the document. 2) ensure that the DS control does not get placed off the page.

Comment: 1), it does has actual text 'Ship to:', 2) it's not DS Control, It was packed in XML body in envelope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some problems with your XML.  I haven't fully checked it all but I can at least see one problem with your definition for the checkbox.  Right now you have:

```
<CheckBoxTabs>
<documentId>1</documentId>
<CheckBox>
   <anchorString>ShipTo:</anchorString>
   <anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>
   ...
```

You need to move the `<documentId>` element into each individual checkBox tab which in this case you have only one.  You also need to get the casing right on the `<checkboxTabs>` and `checkbox` tags.

```
<checkboxTabs>
    <checkbox>
    <documentId>1</documentId>
    <anchorString>ShipTo:</anchorString>
    <anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>
    ...
```

I just ran a test and the following worked perfectly for me:

```
<envelopeDefinition>
    <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Checkbox test, no tab label</emailSubject>
    <status>sent</status>
    <documents>
        <document>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
            <name>test.pdf</name>
        </document>
    </documents>
    <recipients>
        <signers>
            <signer>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <email>john.doe@email.com</email>
                <name>John Doe</name>
                <tabs>
                    <checkboxTabs>
                        <checkbox>
                            <xPosition>100</xPosition>
                            <yPosition>100</yPosition>
                            <documentId>1</documentId>
                            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                        </checkbox>
                    </checkboxTabs>
                </tabs>
            </signer>
        </signers>
    </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: I did put documentID in <checkbox>.

Comment: I did put documentID in <checkbox> section, I can see initial & sign tag, but can not see checkbox. I use webService to sent XML request , Not DS Control.

Comment: documentID is in <checkbox>.   I can see initial & sign tag, but can not see checkbox.  Text is in PDF.  I use webService             <tabs>
                   <signHereTabs>...works!
                   <initialHereTabs>...works!
                   <CheckBoxTabs>--no luck
                        <CheckBox>     <anchorString>Ship to:</anchorString>                                                  
                           <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                           <Selected>true</Selected>
                       </CheckBox>
                   </CheckBoxTabs>
               </tabs>

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer, try using lower case like you do for initialHere and signHere tabs.  Also see Larry's answer as you might be placing the tab off the page.

Comment: I use lower case, still not working.  remove initlhere and sighhere. keep checkbox. still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ergin's answer, I notice that you've got large offsets (1 and 2 inches).

To debug, first remove all offsets. Also minimize the anchor text in case the document text includes extra characters. Eg, try with anchor text of "Ship".

Or even better, start with no anchor text, check that the check box is as you'd expect, then build from there.

Comment: Thanks for answer!, unfortunately, not working. 1) revmove anchor Text, 2) change anchor text to single word. 3) minimize offset.  I only see initial tag and sign tag.  I want to add 3 tags(1.signature, 2 initial, 3. Checkbox) in request XML, but I only see 2 tags in PDF file. checkbox still does not show up....

Comment: one funny thing is when I remove signature and initial elements. only keep checkbox element, when I got email back and [Review Document],I can see Fields list on left part(signature, initial, date signed, name, first name, last name, email address, company, title, text, checkbox).
I can drag checkBox to PDF. but that not what I want. I need to build it in XmL.

Comment: I tried camel case <checkBoxTabs><checkBox>, still no luck :(

Comment: this is the simple one I test, no luck
<envelopeDefinition xmlns=http://www.docusign.com/restapi> 
<emailSubject>x</emailSubject> 
<emailBlurb>x</emailBlurb> 
<status>sent</status> 
<documents>x</documents> 
<recipients> 
<signers> 
<signer> 
<recipientId>1</recipientId> 
<email>x</email> 
<name>x</name> 
<tabs> 
<checkboxTabs>
 <Checkbox> 
 <DocumentID>1</DocumentID> 
</Checkbox> 
</checkboxTabs> 
</tabs> 
</signer> 
</signers> 
</recipients> 
</envelopeDefinition>

Comment: You still have capital letter on the outer xml tag `<Checkbox>` ?

Comment: The problems is with your casing as we've been commenting on. I just ran a test and got it to work, I will modify my answer please test and accept if it works for you.

Comment: Ergin, thanks, It works. the checkbox was too tiny, I can barely see it.  just for little tiny c, not Big C.